# DDD, Aggregates and Entities

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have a following domain object structure

```
Invoice
 - List<Items>
      - Service
```

Invoice has a list of items, and each of that items has a service.

DB Structure is following

```
Invoices Table
Items Table (fk to invoice, fk to service)
Services Table
```

If i understood correctly, Invoice is aggregate, items are entities and service is value object for Item in this scenario?

What happens if i need to add new services to database. Should i create a new `Service` class, which will then be aggregate for that scenario, and have it's own repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Invoice
 - List<Items>
      - Service
```

First thing to note - that's a description of *structure*.  The motivation of aggregates in DDD isn't structure, but *behavior*.  The role of an aggregate is to ensure that a modification made to the structure conforms to the business rules.

> If i understood correctly, Invoice is aggregate, items are entities and service is value object for Item in this scenario?

Close, but the terminology is a bit more murky than that (sorry).  If this structure represents the state within an aggregate boundary, then `Invoice` will be an entity that acts as the `aggregate root`, and the aggregate itself will normally be called the `Invoice aggregate`.

Items and Service might be value types, or they might be entities.  You'd need more information to know for sure.  Guessing from the names (which should be taken from the ubiquitous language), they are probably both entities.  `ServiceName` or `ServiceId` are more likely to be value types.

An important point: if these are entities, their life cycles are subordinate to that of the `Invoice`.  In other words, a "cascade delete" of the invoice would take the items and the service with it.

> What happens if i need to add new services to database. Should i create a new Service class, which will then be aggregate for that scenario, and have it's own repository?

Slightly backwards: the persistence component supports the domain model, not the other way around.

If Service is an entity, and that entity has a life cycle that is independent of any one invoice (for instance, if two different invoices can refer to the "same" Service), then the Service entity should be in a different aggregate than the Invoice, and the state of the invoice contains a reference to the service, rather than the service itself.

If that's the right model, then it follows that the Service aggregate will have its own repository.

Comment: so as the service can be shared with multiple invoices, in this case Item object should not contain Service object, rather than that it should only have ServiceId ?

Comment: so as the service can be shared across aggregate boundaries, etc, yes.

Comment: Is this some general rule or recommendation from the blue book?

Comment: Yes, it's a consequence of treating an aggregate as a consistency boundary.  See Chapter 6 for the discussion of aggregates.  Also, review what Evans has to say about aggregates in this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lE6Hxz4yomA

Comment: Thanks. Beer is yours :D

Answer (score 0):

Can Services exist on their own? - it looks like they can based on what you have above.

If you need to add new services to the database (and I'm assuming a service is standalone), then you need to create a Service aggregate root. There will also be a Service repository etc for adding it.

Aggregate roots and repositories are always one-to-one. They key is understanding what are the aggregate roots in your domain. Once you define these correctly, the repositories are self-defined.

Note that if you ever needed to add something like a new Item to the Invoice in your example above, you would have to do this through the Invoice repository. The simple reason for this is because Item is an entity and is not an aggregate root.

Comment: so should Item hold reference to Service, or it should just have ServiceID instead?

Comment: It depends. But most likely in the situation you have described, ServiceID on its own would suffice